# Sum of sgn of permutation

Tags: summation, permutations

What is the sum of sign of permutation, i.e.
$$
\sum_{\pi \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\pi),
$$
where $\pi$ is the permutation of $S_n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $n>1$, the answer is $0$: $\operatorname{sgn}: S_n \to \{1,-1\}$ is a homomorphism, so its kernel $\operatorname{sgn}^{-1}(1)$ is a normal subgroup of index $2$. Hence $\lvert \operatorname{sgn}^{-1}(1) \rvert = \lvert \operatorname{sgn}^{-1}(-1) \rvert$.

(If $n=1$, the answer is $1$, of course.)

Comment: Unless $n=1$, that is.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to see the sum as the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix with all entries $1$. What is that determinant?

Comment: Yes, I also thought about this possibility. But, I'm not happy with this. For example, you could have $-1+1-1+1$ or $-1+1-1$.

Comment: @Immanuel: Yes, it's just a trick. A cleaner way is to see there are as many even permutations as there are odd. Fix an odd permutations $\tau$, and consider the map $\sigma \mapsto \tau \circ \sigma.$ bijection between even and odd

Comment: So you mean it vanishes?

Comment: @Immanuel: Yes, it is $0$. It's a good question!

Comment: So, does the following also vanishes: $\sum_{\pi \in S_n} \frac{1}{\text{sgn}(\pi)}
$?

Comment: @Immanuel: Since sign has values $\pm 1$,  it is in fact the previous sum. So again $0$.  ( All of this for $n\ge 2$. If $n=1$, you just get $1$)

Comment: I guessed that. But, it does not match to rest of my calculations!

Answer (score 1):

If $ n \ge 2$, then $\pi \to \pi (1 2)$ is a (self-inverse) bijection between even and odd permutations. So then the sum equal $0$, For $n=1$ we just have $\pi((1)) = 1$.

Comment: For $n\geq 2$, the sgn is a group epimorphism. Thus each image is taken on the same number of times.